# Ruby on Rails custom routes or how to get request.request_url before the controller is initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, request, uri

I am trying to do something for hours and I'm stuck with rails routes.

So.. the idea is to have some even more user-friendly urls like for example /Laptops for a category and /Laptops/Apple-MacBook-Air-and-so-on. I should also use such links for simple pages like /MyDummyPage etc.

So my idea was to get the request_url and check if i can find the page myself. But it seems rails is initialising this request class after defining routes and right before calling the controller.

As you can see I am stuck and can't see any possible solution for my problem.
I will be glad if someone can help me.

Thank you in advance.
All the best!

Comment: Can you post some code?  Your routes.rb file would be good to start.

Comment: My routes are useless. That is the idea:
1) I pass the query_string to an model (url mapper)
2) It returns the controller and the action

I found a way to do that by simply create mach for every single possibility by using each e.g. for each categories i create a mach

But this way it go really slow, because it generates matches every time i hit the link. Probably this won't happen in production using passenger but i can't take that risk.

Have you ever tried something like this?

Comment: I don't understand why you consider your routes to be useless.  You shouldn't need to loop through every possible category to find the match, that's what the routes file is for, something like `get ':category' => 'products#category'` in the routes file should get you there.  The thing is that the routes file is read from top to bottom, so you want to keep that in mind when matching against more user friendly, but less standard URLs.

Answer (score 0):

(Whole thing revised)

If you want to allow dynamic matches along with normal restful routes, there are a couple options- (put it at the end of your routes or it will match everything)

```
match '*raw' => 'dynamic#show'
```

And in dynamic_controller.rb

```
def show
  parts = params[:raw].split '/'
  # do logic here to set all variables used in views
  render @resource_or_page
end
```

You could also use the input in a search function and redirect to the first result of that search. Or return a 404 if there are no results.

```
def show
  results = search_method_here params[:raw].sub('/', ' ')
  if results.any?
    redirect_to results.first        
  else
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new 'Not Found'
  end
end
```

Also, for freindlier urls within restful routes, try out this: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

---

I think its important to realize that people generally do not manipulate URLs by hand, and its nice to have readable urls, but its more important for them to be clear on what/where they are doing/going.

In response to your comment, I think you are mislead about routing. If you make 2 routes `:category` and `:page`, they match the exact same url, except one of them stores it in `params[:category]` and the other in `params[:page]`. To differentiate it, you would need to have a different amount of arguments matched like `:category/:product` or a namespace, or, perhaps, a restful route which specifies the MVC the route routes to.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that i can't use this mach for both categories and pages. I want to exclude the keywords and ids, so if I have both match ':category(/:product)' and match ':page' it will either load only pages or categories.

Comment: Is it possible doing the search query and execute the controller I want without redirecting and switching urls?

Comment: It's close but is still not the same thing. I wan't to exclude the controller name. I guess it is impossible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ive read up on some stuff and rewrote the answer. Glad you asked about this im learning a fair bit!

Comment: That was useful. Thank you. I would like to ask you one more question. Is it possible to execute(render) another controller from the dynamic one. What i mean is to simulate execution of categories controller for example, without redirecting on switching urls

Comment: yeah you can render any view you want. The issue is that any variables used in embedded ruby in the view need to be set before you render it. If you call render on the active record object itself, it will find the correct view in the views folder for the object, like for categories you would put _category.html.erb in views/categories/ and access the object in the partial with just `category` (no @ symbol). Then you can put `<%= render @object_holding_a_category %>` anywhere in your views. Thats how I'd do it- make a partial for each object that is just like its show page